# JavaScript subtract elements from string

Tags: c#, javascript

I am sending to JavaScript function string from C# which is ***"11-2-2013"***, and expect in JavaScript function that string, but I am gating 11 - 2 - 2013 = ***-2004***.

C# code:

```
string id = 11 + '-' + 2 + '-' + 2013;
textBoxBO.Attributes.Add("onblur", "TextBoxReset(this," + id + ")");
```

JavaScript code:

```
function TextBoxReset(txt, ID) {
    if (txt.value > 0) {
        var textBoxRR = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtRR" + ID);
        textBoxRR.value = 0;
    }
}
```

How to tell JavaScript not to subtract element from that string.

Comment: Seems like it's because the string is getting evaled. Not familiar with C# and that syntax but there should be a way to _not_ eval it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put the date in quotes:

```
textBoxBO.Attributes.Add("onblur", "TextBoxReset(this,\"" + id  + "\")");
```

If you do not put it in quotes, it will be rendered as `TextBoxReset(this, 11-2-2013)`, which will result in `-2004`.